# Typescript overloading functions with union types

Tags: typescript

I want to have a function that takes two union types as parameters but force them to be the same subtype... without having to check the types myself before calling the function.

This is what I have tried:

**The backstory**

For simplicity I will define some types:

```
type Foo = number;
type Bar = [number, number?];
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;
```

I have a function:

```
function fn(x: FooBar, y: FooBar) {}
```

I want to force that `x` and `y` be of the same type. IE allow `fn(Foo, Foo)` and `fn(Bar, Bar)` but not allow `fn(Foo, Bar)` and `fn(Bar, Foo)`. So I decided to overload the function.

```
function fn(x: Foo, y: Foo): void;
function fn(x: Bar, Bar): void;
function fn(x: FooBar, y: FooBar): void {}
```

I request data from an API. I get two objects from the API, I doubt it matters but they will both be of the same type, either both `Foo` or both `Bar`. It depends on what I am asking for.

**The problem**

When I call my function it complains (I'm using `JSON.parse` as a way of simulating the API call):

```
const x: FooBar = JSON.parse("1");
const y: FooBar = JSON.parse("2");
fn(x, y);
```

> Argument of type 'FooBar' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '[number, number?]'.   Type 'number' is not assignable to type
>   '[number, number?]'.

If I check the types before hand it works:

(side note: I wish there was an easier way to check the type when using declared types)

```
if(typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') fn(x, y);
else if(Array.isArray(x) && Array.isArray(y)) fn(x, y);
```

but this seems silly, I don't want to have to check the types before I call the function, when in the end the call will be the exact same.

Somewhat surprisingly using `or` doesn't work (even though I still don't want to have to do this)

```
if((typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') ||
  (Array.isArray(x) && Array.isArray(y))) {
    fn(x, y); // same error as above
}
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-overload-union-type-error?file=index.ts)

Is there anyway to do what I want? Maybe using a different pattern or approach.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do some kind of type checking before you call `fn(x, y)`, since all the compiler knows is that `x` and `y` are both type `foobar`, and you have declared `fn` such that it only accepts two `foo` parameters or two `bar` parameters, and not both.  *You* know that `x` and `y` will both be `number` (a.k.a. `foo`), but that's because you've done the work of `JSON.parse()` in your head and concluded that the types will be okay.  The compiler isn't that clever.  For all it knows, `x` could be a `foo` and `y` could be a `bar`, and then `fn(x, y)` should not work.  That is: the error on `fn(x,y)` without type checking is a good error that helps you write better code.

Thus the most straightforward way to call the overloaded `fn` on `x` and `y` is the type checking you did here:

```
if (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') fn(x, y);
else if (Array.isArray(x) && Array.isArray(y)) fn(x, y);
```

Yes, it's redundant.  Trying to collapse those into a single statement:

```
if ((typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') ||
  (Array.isArray(x) && Array.isArray(y))) {
  fn(x, y); // error 
}
```

doesn't work, as you've seen.  Dealing properly with call signatures of union types is an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294).  In particular, the types of `x` and `y` are correlated subtypes of `foobar` (meaning they are either both `foo` or both `bar`), but the compiler is not able to handle this.  I've run into this numerous times and have even [suggested a way of dealing with this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) (which won't be adopted, poor me), but for now there's no great solution.

The simplest thing you can do here if you don't want redundant runtime code (in exchange for some compile time clutter) is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
if ((typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number') ||
  (Array.isArray(x) && Array.isArray(y))) {
  (fn as (x: foobar, y: foobar) => void)(x, y); // okay
}
```

}

Here you're *asserting* that inside the type-checked block, `fn` can be safely applied to `x` and `y`, even though in the general case it can't be.  Note that as an assertion you are giving up the safety the compiler, in exchange for the freedom of being able to just write the code as you want.

Personally I'd probably leave the redundant type checking you did above and move on.  It has the advantage of compiler-enforced type safety.  But it's up to you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your `fn(foobar,foobar)` will still execute for `fn(foo,bar)` in the StackBlitz example you provided. There is an error reported in the editor, but if you put a `console.log` in the body of `fn`, you'll see it prints out. If you pass `fn(1, [2, 3])`, you'll see that it prints out without issue.

In order to restrict usage to a specific matching here, you could do a type check.

```
type foo = number;
type bar = [number, number?];
type foobar = foo | bar;

function fn(x: foobar, y: foobar): void {
  if (typeof x != typeof y) return;
  console.log(x + " __ " + y);
}

const x: foobar = JSON.parse("1");
const y: foobar = JSON.parse("2");

// Executes
fn(x, y);
// Doesn't execute
fn(2, [4, 5]);
```

The difficulty here arises because you are defining a type `foobar`, which now always matches `foo` and `bar` as though they were interchangeable.

Comment: Yes I was doing this initially. But then you wont get any compile errors when you call the function with mixed typing. Thats why I decided to overload the method. I realize there might not be a proper solution to what I want but thought maybe there was some creative way of using generics or something so decided to still ask.